# Sharing configuration file among the projects in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a solution in `asp.net core` and multiple API projects are present inside and that is a kind of micro services architecture. My solution structure looks like below.

```
ABC.API
DEF.API
GHI.API and so on....
```

I also have one more class library project that is having some common functionalities and can be used by all above API projects.

And I want to keep the connection string inside the class library project using `json` file or `config` file because all of the above are connecting to same database and i don't want to repeat those in all the projects.

Problem:

- How to keep the file (json/config) in library project. If placed then after publishing the project how the values will store because it will generate a .dll file.
- How to access the connection string in API projects the reason is I am initializing the connection in API projects.
- I tried by keeping the file in a upper folder and then added the below settings in `Program.cs`.

  ```
  var sharedFolder = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "..\\..", "Shared");
  config..AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(sharedFolder, "SharedSettings.json"), optional: false)
  ```

  But this is not working as after publishing the project separately the folder will not be found.

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this and am I on the right track ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem

I solved is by doing the following.

1. Create Class Library for all your shared dependencies
2. Create folder Called AppSettings in this class library. Store all your json configs in there
3. I then created a static helper class in this class library called `JsonConfiguration.cs` See code

   ```
    public static class JsonConfiguration
   {

   public static IConfiguration ConfigurationContainer { get; private set; }

   public static IConfiguration CreateConfigurationContainer()
   {
       var environment = string.Empty;
       try
       {
           environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
           _logger.Debug($"Found environment variable : {environment}");
           if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(environment))
           {
               _logger.Debug($"Setting up Production appsettings.");
               //WE ARE IN PROD !!
               return ConfigurationContainer = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                   .AddJsonFile($"bin/AppSettings/appsettings.json").Build();
           }

           _logger.Debug($"Setting up {environment} appsettings.");
           return ConfigurationContainer = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
               .AddJsonFile($"bin/AppSettings/appsettings-{environment}.json").Build();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           _logger.Fatal(ex, "{message} {environment}", "Failed Setting up Application Config.", environment);
           throw;
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Make sure your json files are marked as "Copy to output directory" to copy always.

You could then register the IConfiguration in the app that needs it and call `JsonConfiguration.CreateConfigurationContainer()`, I would probably map your connection strings to a a concrete model class and inject where needed. Hope this was enough to get you going.

Comment: Thank you so much for getting time to reply my query, I will be implementing this soon.

Comment: @TufanChand please let me know how it goes :)

Comment: I did little bit of changes to it and it worked like a charm man Thank you so much

Comment: @TufanChand glad i was able to guide you in the right direction!